# OrbitControl or TrackballControl

Tags: three.js

I've read a lot about these 2 controls and currently I'm using TrackballControls.

I need to rotate an object along all three axis (Both controls already do that), but **I also need to set sometimes a new camera position/rotation by hand**. And this doesn't really work.

My workaround is to 
disable the trackballcontrols, 
get the quaternions-object of the new position, 
apply these to camera.up
and then enable the camera

But as mentioned, this doesn't really work stable.

I read that OrbitControls could be a better solution for such a task. But OrbitControls has a "limit" on vertical rotation of objects and I need to rotate my objects without limits.

So my questions are:

**1.** Which Controls System is more suitable for my task

**2.** If it's Trackball - how would you set manually a new camera position and rotation? And if it's Orbit - is there a way to disable this vertical rotation limit?

Thanks a lot!!

Regards - Misa

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all, `TrackballControls` and `OrbitControls` rotate the *camera*, not the objects.

Second, `OrbitControls` enforces the camera `up` direction, and `TrackballControls` allows the camera to rotate upside-down.

`TrackballControls` has a `reset()` method, which restores the `target` (center of rotation), camera `position`, and camera `up` vector to their original settings.

```
controls.reset();
```

The above code will restore the original `position`, `target`, and `up` vector. You can change those too, if you want, before you call `controls.reset()`.

```
controls.position0.set( 0, 0, 10 ); // set a new desired position
controls.target0.set( 0, 0, 0 ); // set a new target
controls.up0.set( 0, 1, 0 ); // set a new up vector
controls.reset();
```

Read the `reset()` function source code so you understand what it is doing.

EDIT: `OrbitControls` now has a `reset()` method, too. Check the source code.

three.js r.82

Comment: Dear WstLangley - thank you very much for this answer. Is there a way to animate the camera to the new position? This position resetting seems to work pretty nice. But what if I wish to change the camera.rotation? This doesn't seem to work, since the reset() function does not reset the camera.rotation. Is there a way to reset this also? I would like to give you a reputation point, but I still don't have enough reputations to do so. Thanks - Misa

Comment: Strange behaviour: After rotating the camera I do following:
var q = new THREE.Quaternion(); q.setFromRotationMatrix(camera.matrix); controls.up0.applyQuaternion(q);  controls.position0 = camera.position.clone(); controls.reset();          This only works for the first time - so after the reset() the camera stays in the manually rotated position. When I try to do it again it doesn't work, so the camera jumps to an other angle after the reset() function.

Comment: 1. If you want to manipulate the rotation or quaternion directly, then you will have to re-write the code to do so. These controls were not designed for that. 2. You are asking a new question regarding animation. You need to make a new post if you have a different question. 3. I can't debug your code for you, I can only answer questions about three.js. You can make a new post if you want to ask about problems with your code. 4. You "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. You have enough reputation to do that. Please do so. I did answer your original question. Thank you.

Comment: Hey WestLangley - Thanks a lot. You are completely right about points 1 to 4. In fact I have successfully rewritten the code and achieved the rotation. I will post a new question regarding the animation. - Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To force TrackballControls' to rotates only horizontal, find the implementation of function `getMouseProjectionOnBall` and add a single line:

```
var getMouseProjectionOnBall = (function() {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    var objectUp = new THREE.Vector3();
    var mouseOnBall = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function(pageX, pageY) {
      mouseOnBall.set(
        (pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left) / (_this.screen.width * 0.5),
        (_this.screen.height * 0.5 + _this.screen.top - pageY) / (_this.screen.height * 0.5),
        0.0);

      mouseOnBall.setY(0); // add this

      var length = mouseOnBall.length();
```

I'm still working on limit the angle in a range rather than disabling it...