# Documentation for three.js controls?

Tags: three.js

three.js comes with many useful controls, which cause camera movement in response to keyboard and mouse input.

They are all at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls and accessed in the code as e.g.`THREE.OrbitControls` .

However, I can't find any documentation or comments that says what situation to use what control for or what they are intended to do.

Can anyone point me to this information, or do I have to analyze the code to figure out if, for example, I prefer `FlyControls` to `FirstPersonControls`?

Comment: At least the `THREE.OrbitControls` source code has a few lines of comments explaining how it works/why it exists at the start of the file. That's much better than I can say for `THREE.TrackballControls` which has a grand total of 21 comments, most of them fewer than 9 characters long and none of which explain why the file exists or how to use it.

Comment: Some helpful information about orbit vs. trackball controls is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581760/423105

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation for the controls does exist, but it was deleted from the repository [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/b63ad21659ae42095f090d2ea5d3fb930d17d11d). Seems like a bizarre thing to do, but there is an explanation of sorts [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4175). I guess the docs were very incomplete anyway and it was easier to delete them than to finish them. :-p

Comment: Looks like only the FirstPersonControls were documented at that time; the rest were just empty boilerplate. Now there is [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) in the documentation, luckily that is the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The source code for most of the controls contains pretty decent comments. I know this isnt as good as proper documentation but it really helps to get a handle on how to set up the controls

Answer (score -10):

The Controls are named by their purpose or the idea they implement. OrbitControls allow you to orbit around some kind of object. Same for Trackball-Controls although the trackball-scheme implies that the camera will rotate around without the up-Axis staying as it was like in orbit-controls. Fly and FPS-Controls are self-explanatory.
Just try the examples and you will see what the difference is. No need to analyse code. Just depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: You seriously think the controls are self-explanatory from the name? "Fly" and "Path" and "PointerLock" and "Oculus" and "Transform"? Each one of these is not obvious and has a host of parameters that are in themselves not obvious. Sadly, I'm afraid you may be right; there's just no documentation. Absurd. I'll leave it a while longer in hopes that someone will be able to point to a useful reference.

Comment: Yes i think the controls are self-explanatory. Maybe just ask what you do not understand. As there are examples for all the controls, where is the problem? Fly = Fly-Mode, path-controls let you choose a path to move along and Oculus is of course meant to be used with the Oculus Rift Head Mounted Display. And as there are examples for EVERY controls-type, this is no big deal to choose the correct one for your use case but I guess you do not even know what you want. Also it seems you don't want to google for your answer because for Trackball or Pointerlock you could find the ideas behind them.

Comment: anyway, good luck reading through all the code for all controls until you know what they are for O.o