# OrthographicCamera with OrbitControls in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, orthographic

I have developed a simple `three.js` application that renders a cube, and which have several buttons to set fixed camera positions.

The function associated with each button sets the camera position and orientation by doing `camera.position.set(vector)`, and `camera.lookAt(center_of_bounding_box)`. `camera` is a `OrthographicCamera` of `three.js`, and `vector` and `center_of_bounding_box` are both instances of the `three.js` class `Vector3`.

When I pan the cube, and set a fixed view, it is rendered correctly. However, when I pan it again, the application moves it, like if the controls had some kind of offset.

I am very new to `three.js`, and I could not resolve this problem searching on the web, because the given solutions seem to me that solve another issues. Should I do something in the `OrbitControls` when I set the camera position and orientation manually? Any help to face this issue will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It seems that this is simple enough to provide a minimal (not) working example of. You should add a code snippet if want more people to help.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581225/orbitcontrol-or-trackballcontrol/18581760#18581760).

Comment: @WestLangley, thank you so much. In the answer that you have suggested I found the necessary information to solve the issue.